# Search exact multiple pattern in file and delete line if pattern matches

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

For example, a file with content like this, which doesn't contain any duplicate entries:

```
100
10012
12345
12387
123
123456344
```

I want to search `100` and `12345` in the above file and delete the line if the pattern matches.

Also I want to do this in a single command.

Comment: Why was this question down-voted? An explanation in the comments would be nice.

Answer (score 7):

I would simply do

```
egrep -v '^(100|12345)$' file.in > file.out
```

Or, with sed

```
sed -n '/^\(100\|12345\)$/!p' file.in > file.out
```

you don't even need a second file:

```
sed -ni '/^\(100\|12345\)$/!p' file.in
```

(see the comments; strictly speaking, a temporary file is created which then replaces the input file, however this is transparent for the user)

As you see, the regular expression stays more or less the same (except that you don't need to escape ()| in egrep). If you have more than one word on a line, but only want to match whole words, you can use the following sed regex:

```
sed -n '/\<\(100\|12345\)\>/!p' file.in > file.out
```

This will match lines `100`, `123 100 123` but not `123 100123`.

To get the same behaviour with `grep`, use the `-w` option (thanks Janito):

```
egrep -wv '(100|12345)' file.in > file.out
```

Comment: I would also add that if you want it to match `100` and not say `10012`, you should add the `-w` flag to indicate grep to match whole words.

Comment: sorry its not working. This command is also removing the 10012 and 123456344.  Output after using this command is :::          Desktop$ egrep -v '(^100|12345)' Untitled\ Document
12387 
123

Comment: "You don't need a second file" is incorrect as `sed -i` uses a temporary file.

Comment: @WilliamPursell strictly speaking, yes; however from the user point of view, no additional file is permanently created.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/\(100\|12345\)/d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers must match exactly, you can use an extended grep pattern like this:

```
 grep -v -E '^(100|12345)$' inputfile
```

This says: *print all lines which are not 100 or 12345*. If the numbers need to match only at the beginning of the line, use

```
 grep -v -E '^(100|12345)' inputfile
```

If they can match anywhere, use

```
 grep -v -E '(100|12345)' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed '/^\(100\|12345\)$/d' file.txt
```

Results:

```
10012
12387
123
123456344
```